# How to encode IDN on apache?

Tags: apache, idn

I need to rewrite requests in apache to a directory.

While most browsers convert it to Punycode (Bücher.ch -> xn--bcher-kva.ch) some of the request is encoded to ascii (Bücher.ch -> B%C3%BCcher.ch).

My directories is in Punycode, meaning, I'm redirecting "Bücher.ch" to a directory named "xn--bcher-kva.ch".

Any idea on how to encode request into Punycode so i can direct them the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? What do you mean by "direct"?

Comment: direct Bücher.ch to /srv/domains/xn--bcher-kva.ch (a directory on my server). create a RewriteRule that forward the domain to a directory.